# Проблемы с QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, qtableview

У меня проблемы с `QTableView`. Создал `model`:

```
 class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
 {
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
      TableModel(QObject* parent);
      int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
      int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
      QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
 };
```

Создаю `QTableView` в нее записываю модель:

```
QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();
tableView->setModel(mTableModel);
mTableModel->data(mTableModel->index(3,3, QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()), Qt::DisplayRole);
```

и не  знаю что передавать в 3 параметр тут:

```
mTableModel->data(mTableModel->index(3,3, QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()), Qt::DisplayRole);
```

Вместо - `QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex())`.

Что сюда нужно передавать? А правильно ли я передаю все в `data()`?
В `data` я  делаю:

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex&index, int role) const
{
   if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
   {
      return QString("Row%1, Column%2")
               .arg(index.row() + 1)
               .arg(index.column() +1);
   }
   return QVariant();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не передавайте, там и так значение по умолчанию передается – [QModelIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html).

Параметр `parent` нужен для иерархических моделей, например для [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html)

Comment: Так  норм?  QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();
    tableView->setModel(mTableModel);
    mTableModel->data(mTableModel->index(3,3), Qt::DisplayRole);

Comment: The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Вроде бы, нормально. А в модели есть данные? А модель 4 на 4?

Comment: уже все ок я просто model пустую  создал, и не инициализовал

Comment: Отметьте тогда ответ :)